# Can I use External JSON weather data in business catalyst and use with liquid?

Tags: json, liquid, business-catalyst

Im trying to create a LIVE weather app using liquid in Business Catalyst.

I can get the live data from http://openweathermap.org/

using this: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dubbo

And i thought i could insert it into an include using:

{module_json json="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dubbo" template="/_System/Includes/tpl/current.tpl"}

Im just not sure what exactly to call in the template. Am i going about this all wrong?

I know there has to be a way to call the Json data not sure if the tag supports external urls...

Please help and if you know how you would call the data that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [the `module_json` tag](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/module-reference/general/module_json.html) does not support accessing external JSON data. When attempting to use it in that way, it will only render:

```
<!-- No input data found -->
```

Comment: Ah! i did notice that! well at least i know i linked everything ok... Thank you.. Any idea as to when theat may be a possiblity or if there is another way to injest external data?

Comment: @James it's unlikely that `module_json` will ever fetch remote files, for both security and performance reasons. I'd start with `jQuery.getJSON`.

Comment: Great Thanks Clement! and thanks for pointing me in that direction!